# How to look up users' specific answers?

Tags: support, tagging, search

I am looking for a search function that describes users' answers with their tags as the variable. For example, if I wanted to look up Scott's answers with the restriction that it is limited to **soft-question**, how could I do that?

Comment: Related: [How to intersect users and tags?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4051/how-to-intersect-users-and-tags). Although that question does not ask about restriction to answers only.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This query](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A74240+[soft-question]+is%3Aanswer) which can be entered into the search box as

`user:74240 [soft-question] is:answer`

should give you what you are asking for. If you meant a different Scott, find their user-id and substitute that.

As Martin Sleziak mentions, you can go to the profile page for a particular user and click on a tag to list the questions and answers that user has written in that tag.

Comment: Can I substitute the word "answer" for anything?

Comment: @DonLarynx Unfortunately, `is:hint` and `is:rant` are not yet supported by SE; the only options are `is:answer` and `is:question` . Click "Advanced Search Tips" on the right [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aanswer).

Comment: Perhaps it is worth mentioning that if you go to the [tags tab](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/74240/scott?tab=tags) on the profile page of some particular user and you click on some of the tags, you already get search for *all posts* of the particular user in that tag. (This seems to be quicker than typing that into search box.) Then you just have to modify the search by adding `is:answer` or `is:question` (or whatever further things you want to include in your search query).

Comment: Wait - M.SE supports *rants*, now?